# Subversion not available in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, svn

This is VERY weird. I've been using Eclipse for over 4 years, and for some reason my Subversion integration disappeared today. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Subclipse 3 times already and it never re-appears. My installation log and configuration shows subclipse installed, but all I have under 'Team' in preferences is 'CVS', no Subversion. What would make this happen?

**UPDATE**

After an upgrade to eclipse via update-manager on Ubuntu, my team provider plugins appeared again and are working perfectly. Very bizarre.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What version of Subclipse? Do you have the right version of JavaHL: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL ? Did you update or install any other software recently?

Comment: I just noticed that HgEclipse is not working either. All my addon Team Providers are not available. 

Eclipse SDK

Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343

I have the proper version of JavaHL according to that compatibility table. No new software as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by deleting both my ~/.eclipse directory and my workspace directory. I then reinstalled the Subclipse and MercurialEclipse plugins and SVN/Mercurial show up as Team Synchronization options.

Comment: Exactly same symptoms today with Eclipse Kepler. The whole SVN kit and kaboodle seems to have been *uninstalled* (even if (some?) files are still on disk)! Deleted the .eclipse and workspace directories, reinstalled SVN and connectors, reimported the project, everything back to normal. +1

Answer (score 0):

Any luck?  Maybe try Subversive if for some reason Subclipse does not work.  Also verify that you didn't remove svn from the system path.

Comment: I like the Subversive suggestion since I can't get Subclipse to work with Eclipse either.